# SMTP is not delivering my email without any error

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, smtp

I have a website where I send an email using smtp to users who register.
They offer their email and I store it in a session. Then, I send a code to their email for configuration.
When I register my email, I get an email without any problem, but no one else is getting emails.

I am using a personal account for sending email using smtp server.
I am using AWS amazon servers to send the emails.
I have enabled Less Secure App in email security setting.
I have disabled 2 step Verification for my email.
I have allowed the amazon server to sign in and use my email, as it prompted for me in inbox.

THE WEBSITE LINK IS HERE ---->
[My Website](http://gaming-boat.com)

the smtp code in C#

```
 Random code = new Random();
            int code_value = code.Next(100000, 999999);
            var toAddress = new MailAddress(context.Session["confirm_email"].ToString(), "Megalodon Account");
            string subject = "Use This Code to Confirm Your Account";
            string body = code_value + " is your code";
            var gmail_smtp = new SmtpClient
            {

                Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
                Port = "587",
                UseDefaultCredentials = false,
                EnableSsl = true,
                DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
                Credentials = new NetworkCredential(new MailAddress("mygmail", "Megalodon Account").Address, "mypassword"),
                Timeout = 20000
            };

            context.Session["email_confirm_code"] = email + "/" + code_value + "/0";
            context.Session.Timeout = 5;
           
            using (var gmail_message = new MailMessage(new MailAddress("mygmail", "Megalodon Account"), toAddress)
            {
                Subject = subject,
                Body = body
            })
            {

                try
                {
                    gmail_smtp.Send(gmail_message);

                }
                catch (Exception)
                {

                }
            }
```

Comment: Your email could be on a blacklist and being blocked in some clients, also, Microsoft recommend SmtpClient class not to be used anymore, they encourage people to use other open source smtp librarys, take a look on MailKit library

Comment: I have a friends who uses the same technique, and it is working perfectly.